# Deploying python API in heroku without static files

Tags: python, django, heroku

I'm deploying a django API which does not have any static files, When is deploy it using **heroku** via **GitHub** without using heroku CLI, I get an error

> Error while running '$ python Rest_Api/manage.py collectstatic --noinput'.

**NB** In my settings file i have the default django
`STATIC_URL = '/static/'`

How can i tell heroku my app does not have any statics thus should not expect it?

Answer (score 0):

you will want your admin panel to look good when deployed and they do have static files. so deploy as you would deploy django with static files